# What size electrical breaker and wire do I need for a 230 volt, 40amp. cutterhead motor?

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

I need to know what size wire and breaker I need to wire in a 230 volt 40 amp. cutterhead motor

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your question if you want to change it instead of posting it a second time. Thanks, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the nameplate on the motor, or the model number?

Comment: That's one heck of a home improvement. Alternatively, it's dubious as to on-topic-ness.

Answer (score 2):

- 40 ampere breaker
- 8 AWG copper, or 6 AWG aluminum conductors (See National Electrical Code 2014 Table 310.15(B)(16)).